# AFNetworking missing setCompletionBlock ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, afnetworking-2, progress, download

I trying to download a pdf file from url with progress. All it's ok. But i can't found setCompletionBlock, why?
This is my working code:

```
println("progress: \(0.0)")

    let request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: document.link)!)
    let operation: AFURLConnectionOperation = AFHTTPRequestOperation(request: request)
    let paths: NSArray = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)
    let filePath: NSString = paths.objectAtIndex(0).stringByAppendingPathComponent("pdf_\(document.id).pdf")
    operation.outputStream = NSOutputStream(toFileAtPath: filePath, append: false)

    operation.setDownloadProgressBlock({(bytesRead, totalBytesRead, totalBytesExpectedToRead) -> Void in

        var total: CGFloat = CGFloat(totalBytesRead) / CGFloat(totalBytesExpectedToRead)
        println("progress: \(total)")


    })

    //operation.setCompletionBlock ... can't found this block?!

    operation.start()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are casting your `AFHTTPRequestOperation` to a `AFURLConnectionOperation`:

```
let operation: AFURLConnectionOperation = AFHTTPRequestOperation(request: request)
```

But `setCompletionBlockWithSuccess` is defined in `AFHTTPRequestOperation`, not `AFURLConnectionOperation`.

Instead, just let `operation` be a `AFHTTPRequestOperation`:

```
let operation = AFHTTPRequestOperation(request: request)
```

Then it will recognize `setCompletionBlockWithSuccess` successfully.